# How do I make the official JDK version the default java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make java default to a manually installed JRE/JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159575/how-do-i-make-java-default-to-a-manually-installed-jre-jdk)

I've got the following in /.bashrc

```
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/jdk1.7.0_03/ 
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/jdk1.7.0_03/bin
```

This is fine, if I do $JAVA_HOME I get the directory above.

The problem is if I do java -version I get...

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

How do I make the official jdk version the right one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to get into the command line for this one (although I expect you're happy with that if you've installed the JDK!).

Open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. Then type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

I see you're new to Ubuntu so I'll explain some of these commands. [Sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) tells the computer to execute the following command with the super-user's privileges. You will therefore be asked for your password. [Update-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) keeps track of what your preferred options are when you have several software packages providing similar functionality, such as different JDKs. The rest is just telling update-alternatives what you'd like to configure. **Never enter commands in a terminal if you don't know roughly what they'll do. If in doubt, enter `man <command name>` in the terminal to read the command's manual.**