# jdk-12.0.1 installed, but java --version command showing openjdk-11.0.3

Tags: software-installation, java, openjdk

I wanted to run my app.jar via terminal with `java -jar` command, and I have gotten the following error:

> Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

which surprised me, because when I was setting everything up, I have downloaded and installed `jdk-12.0.1` from java.sun.com.
Also, `JAVA_HOME` path in `/etc/environment` is set to the `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-12.0.1` directory. But when I run `java --version`, it shows me:

```
openjdk 11.0.3 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Can anyone explain why is that so and what should I do to configure everything properly?

Comment: Have you set your default javac, javaws and java version? This may be answered before, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/121654/how-to-set-default-java-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system-level Java is still configured as OpenJDK 11. To manage multiple Java installations properly, you should register the Oracle/Open JDK 12 that you have manually downloaded so that Ubuntu can recognize it. After that, you can configure the specific Java version that you want using `update-alternatives`. The commands below will register the new Java installation and set it as the first priority:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-12.0.1/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-12.0.1/bin/javac" 1
```

If you only need a single Java installation, it would be easier to install the latest Java as a system package via the official repositories or ppa:

**OpenJDK 12**:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-12-jdk
```

**Oracle JDK 12**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt install oracle-java12-installer
```

Comment: Thank you!
Whoever face this problem,another nice solution also is here https://askubuntu.com/questions/162159/how-do-i-make-the-official-jdk-version-the-default-java.