# Configure what JVM Eclipse runs in

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I configure what JVM Eclipse runs in?

I'm trying to switch it to use my installed `java-6-sun` so that I can use `jstack` to figure out why Eclipse is spinning endlessly in certain situations.

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04, and I'm using the pre-packaged Ubuntu Eclipse 3.7.2.

I tried to adding the `-vm` option to `eclipse.ini` (immediately above the `-vmargs` line in my `/etc/eclipse.ini`), but `top` still shows that Eclipse is running with plain old `/usr/bin/java`.

The [Ubuntu community wiki article for Eclipse](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE) mentions `/etc/eclipse/java_home`, which doesn't exist on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may already be using your preferred JVM. Please note that `/usr/bin/java` is *not* a binary, but a symlink pointing to your preferred Java JRE/JDK alternative.

I recommend changing this alternative to Sun Java 6 to avoid any confusion. For how to do that, please see this question:

> [How do I make java default to a manually installed JRE/JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159575/how-do-i-make-java-default-to-a-manually-installed-jre-jdk)

Comment: Changing the system-wide default JVM temporarily is fine for my purpose -- a couple of test runs of something on a single user system -- so I'll take it. But what I was really looking for was a way to configure Eclipse specifically.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to download Eclipse from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ as the one from the Ubuntu repos is always shockingly out of date. Given Java's recent security scandals, I prefer to get the latest JDKs from the website itself http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and I don't need to give them root access.

So in Eclipse to change the default JVM/JRE:
**Window-Preferences-Java-Installed JREs**
from there you can ADD another JVM e.g version 8 etc by pointing to the JVM's location. This also where you can point to JAR libraries.

After check the default JDK:
**Window-Preferences-Java-Compiler-JDK Compiler Compliance Level**-as appropriate e.g 1.8