# Setting JDK 7 as default

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk

```
 four@twenty:~$ file /etc/alternatives/java /etc/alternatives/javac
 /etc/alternatives/java:symbolic link to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java'
 /etc/alternatives/javac:symbolic link to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac'
```

Forgive my noobishness but I am interpreting these messages as the runtime environment using Java 7 but the compiler is using Java 6?

Is this right, and if so, how can I set it to use Java version 7?

Answer (score 159):

Switching between installed Java versions can be accomplished using the `update alternatives` command.

- To get a list of your installed Java platforms, run the following command from the terminal:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config java
  ```

  This will give you a list output similar to this:

  ```
  There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
     Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java         1070      auto mode
    1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
  * 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1069      manual mode
  Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
  ```

In this case, the Open JDK 6 version is running. To switch to the Open JDK version 7, you would select option `1` at the prompt and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You will now be running the OpenJDK 7 version. No other changes will be needed to switch your Java versions.

Comment: Okay thanks. Would I gain anything from uninstalling jkd6?

Comment: @user142712 No problem. I believe that an uninstall would also remove the older browser plugin, which is beneficial security-wise.

Comment: I wouldn't go for the "No problem" answer so fast. Check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html and http://upstream-tracker.org/java/versions/jdk.html. There is no 100% compatibility between those two major versions and it might happen so (unlikely but still...) that you have an application X that cannot run properly with the seventh version. Until you make sure there will be no issues I strongly advice to keep both just in case you need the previous version.

Comment: Just to be clear. The "no problem" comment was another way of me saying you are welcome, I never claimed that there would be no problems with your Java installation.

Comment: you need to do this for `javac` as well in case you wanna change the compiler as well.

Comment: update-alternatives solution provided by this answer will switch **JRE only**. See [below](http://askubuntu.com/a/884124/655398) for the proper way to switch entire **JDK** (compiler and other tools) with one command

Answer (score 17):

The most voted answer which suggests to use

> update-alternatives

only partially answers the question. By using it you very likely to end up with your Java environment being inconsistent.

This is especially important if you have JDK, not JRE, as

> [sudo] update-alternatives --config java

will change version for the the `java` command **only**, i.e. repoint main JRE executable.

`javac` and other JDK tools will still point to the other java version. 
To fully switch you have to continue with `update-alternatives` for all other tools.

The **proper** and **much easier** way to switch Java versions in the Linux distribution with "alternatives" system - i.e. in the Debian or it's derivative Ubuntu - is to use
**update-java-alternatives** command.

> **update-java-alternatives -l** - will list installed Java versions
>
> **[sudo] update-java-alternatives -s**  - will switch to the requested version

[Source](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-java-faq/ch3.en.html)

Comment: THIS! Thank you so much. I wish I could give you internet more points, but I don't think I have that right yet.

Answer (score 10):

You can run `sudo update-alternatives --config java`, and select JDK 7, if it's installed.

Comment: Okay cheers, It says I have two of JKD7 installed one listing status as auto the other manual. Is there any difference?

Comment: There's Info here: http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives but i'd select auto.

Comment: "Each link group is, at any given time, in one of two modes: automatic or manual. When a group is in automatic mode, the alternatives system will automatically decide, as packages are installed and removed, whether and how to update the links. In manual mode, the alternatives system will not change the links; it will leave all the decisions to the system administrator. "

Answer (score 6):

the GUI way

> $ sudo apt-get install galternatives
>
> $ sudo galternatives

more here: https://askubuntu.com/a/159594/216936

Comment: @KevinBowen This installs a GUI application.

Comment: WouterH is right. http://www.debianadmin.com/galternatives-graphical-setup-tool-for-alternatives-configuration-in-ubuntu.html 
thx wouterH