# update-java-alternatives: Only java, but not javac is changed

Tags: 16.04, java, openjdk

I have Java 8 and Java 11 installed in parallel on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine:

```
$ update-java-alternatives --list
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Having selected Java 11 previously, I now wanted to switch to Java 8 using the command

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Yet, only the symlink of `/usr/bin/java`, but not `/usr/bin/javac` is updated:

```
$ javac -version
javac 11.0.5

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

Why is this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/272187/setting-jdk-7-as-default/272190

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --config java` does not work?

Comment: For just `java` or `javac` itself `update-alternatives` works fine, but the (Open)JDK consists of many more Java tools in both the JRE and the JDK. After all, the purpose of `update-java-alternatives` is to (conceptually) run `update-alternatives` for all Java tools defined in the respective .jinfo file.

Answer (score 1):

Java alternatives are configured in .jinfo files, e.g. those in `/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo` and `/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo` in your case. When you look at the Java 8 file, you'll see the following line which configures the path for `javac`, among others for all other Java binaries:

```
jdkhl javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
```

Unfortunately, it seems like the `update-java-alternatives` script is outdated on your system, leading to lines prefixed with `jdkhl` (short for JDK Headless) being ignored. This has also been discussed in Debian bug [`#825987`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825987).

To fix it, just edit `/usr/sbin/update-java-alternatives` according to [this diff](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?att=1;bug=825987;filename=0001-Support-the-jdkhl-alternatives-type.patch;msg=19).