# How to upgrade Java compiler

Tags: java

Today I've started to get this warning in the console, when I try to compile my programs with javac:

> warning: Blabla.class: major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
>
> it is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.

But how can I do that?

PS. command `javac -version` returns 1.7.0_85, while `java -version` returns 1.8.0_66. I do not know how this mixture has happened.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `javac -version`

Comment: @A.B. I've done that.

Comment: Try this command and check, if you can change the active javac version `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`

Comment: I see two alternatives - for java 7 and for java 8.

Comment: Select Java 8. Use the same version as for java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have more than one Java version installed and you are using different versions for `java` and `javac`. `javac -version` returns `1.7.0_85`, while `java -version` returns `1.8.0_66`. This means that `javac`creates bytecode for Java 7 and you try to compile a version for Java 8.

Execute

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

and select Java 8 to solve your problem.

Comment: It was giving me an error that I had no alternative javac available. I was able to solve the issue by following the marked answer of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159575/how-do-i-make-java-default-to-a-manually-installed-jre-jdk).