# how to install tomcat6 in ubuntu 16.04 using apt-get install

Tags: 16.04, tomcat6

Is it possible to install tomcat6 in ubuntu 16.04?
does ubuntu 16.04 supports tomcat6?
when I try to install tomcat 6 using `apt-get install` i got the following message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package tomcat6
```

and when I try to install `libtomcat6-java` got following message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libtomcat6-java is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libtomcat6-java' has no installation candidate
```

help me to install tomcat6 using apt-get 
Thank You.

Comment: `tomcat6` is considered legacy and is not in the official Ubuntu repositories for 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to download the tar file, decompress and move to a directory of your choice. [You can choose a mirror here and get a different download link](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi).

My steps:

```
$ wget http://ftp.unicamp.br/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.53/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.53.tar.gz
$ tar xvzf apache-tomcat-6.0.47.tar.gz
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/tomcat
$ sudo mv apache-tomcat-6.0.47 /usr/local/tomcat
```

I'm almost sure that Tomcat 6 works in Java 6, so additional steps are required if your Ubuntu is using, for instance, Java 8.

As Java 6 is no longer distributed for Ubuntu, you'll need to download a legacy package and install manually, [according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67909/how-do-i-install-oracle-jdk-6).

```
$ chmod a+x jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
$ sudo ./jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
$ mv jdk1.6.0_45 java-6-oracle
$ sudo mv java-6-oracle /usr/lib/jvm
```

And now, you can switch java version using either `update-alternatives` or [`galternatives`](https://askubuntu.com/a/159594/165300).

Additionally, modify your `.bashrc` file to set `JAVA_HOME` variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
```

Comment: This has more details: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

For 6 the apt-get command is

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat6
```

I don't know if that version is still in the repo for Ubuntu 16.04. Otherwise you have to download the tar bundle and install it from there.

- Why do you need 6, not 7 or 8?
- Why are you limited to apt-get?

Manual install is not that difficult if I remember correctly. You should however record precisely what you're doing and copy all config files you edited as backup. When you need to upgrade, you want to know how you did it the first time.

Comment: `tomcat6` doesn't exist for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: But won't a tar download work?

Comment: my application is tomcat 6 compatible, and my unix administration skills are limited.

Comment: @SPRBRN Untarring the tar from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi would work but that's not what your answer is advocating.

Comment: You're in an XY situation. Give us info about the app that you want to install. If it's Tomcat 6 compatible, it might just work under 7 of 8. As those are easy to install, have you tried that?

Comment: If you really need Tomcat 6, you could install it in docker maybe? But first try 8, then 7, via apt. Tomcat is lots of work, when you start out. It can be complex to figure it out, but it's all possible.