# How to install JDK 19 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: server, java, 22.04, jdk

Today, oracle release JDK 19. How to install JDK 19 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

commands

```
wget https://download.oracle.com/java/19/latest/jdk-19_linux-x64_bin.deb

sudo apt-get -qqy install ./jdk-19_linux-x64_bin.deb

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-19/bin/java 1919
```

check result

```
root@vypc:~# java -version
java version "19" 2022-09-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19+36-2238)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19+36-2238, mixed mode, sharing)
```

See https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/03/install-jdk-18-ubuntu/

Comment: You also need to run `update-alternatives` for every other program you want to run, such as `javac`, `javadoc`, and more.  Here are [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53902806/173852) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/159585/35128) that give more complete lists.